# Is there an instant way to make kivy file run in a computer that doesn't have kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I made a kivy coding for my school project. I downloaded kivy so that file could run on my computer. I store the file in the kivy tool folder with the expectation that it can run in my school's computer after I downloaded the whole file. But an unexpected problem surfaced. I downloaded it there a few days ago and it couldn't run. There's no time for me to download kivy just before my presentation. Is there any way to make it instantly run without downloading kivy?

Comment: You can probably use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: Thanks! (Apparently you need more characters to add this comment and can't send a simple thanks so this is it don't care about this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should package your Kivy App using PyInstaller e.g. [Create a package for Windows](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html)

## [PyInstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into
> a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing
> a Python interpreter or any modules.

Comment: Thanks! (Apparently you need more characters to add this comment and can't send a simple thanks so this is it don't care about this)